# In WPF which is better, to use images for icons or XAML paths? Why?

Tags: wpf, image, vector-graphics

Currently I am working on upgrading our company's ERP system to a new major version, and I am currently laying the foundations for the front-end UI using of course WPF, now I want to know whether to use `Image` elements or XAML `Path` objects (vector graphics) for the solution icons (i.e. Add, delete, save, duplicate, search ...etc button icons). From your experience which one is better and why?

Comment: What are you showing? Do you know how to draw it programmatically?

Comment: @RitchMelton, I said icons (i.e. Add, delete, save, duplicate, search button icons). I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with CodeWarrior, but I think there are a lot more factors in this decision, including:

- who is producing the images? You? If so, how do your design talents fare? I know that I, personally, wouldn't have a hope in hell of producing decent looking bitmap icons, and yet I *am* able to produce passably attractive icons in XAML
- will you need to display the icons at various sizes? If so, XAML can again save you a lot of time, since it tends to scale far more crisply
- will you need to display the icons at very small resolutions? If so, XAML icons may actually look less attractive
- XAML icons will give you more flexibility if you need to combine images, or vary them subtly, such as changing their thickness, colors, or "graying them out" when they're disabled
- finally, there's nothing preventing you from having the best of both worlds. In my application, I knew I'd need the primary icon in a lot of places. I designed it in XAML and then wrote a little supporting app that spat it out as a bitmap at various sizes. This made it easy to use as my application icon and it looks crisp at every necessary size (eg. as desktop icon, as a window icon etcetera). In addition, I have used it in the application itself as a XAML resource, such as in the splash screen

Comment: Yes, that's make sense, to have the best of the two worlds :D

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the scope of the images you are planning to display.  If you have a small number of images that are going to be displayed several thousand times, XAML paths make sense.  If they are only a few images displayed a few times, XAML paths would take more time than it would be worth.  Similarly if you have thousands of images that are only displayed once each, go with images as it would take forever to convert to XAML paths (unless you have a method to do it programmatically).

It sounds like you are using a small number of images a few times, so go with images.  It doesn't really take a whole lot of processing power to do it, and the big benefit of WPF is that it offloads graphic rendering stuff to the GPU instead of using the CPU for it.

Comment: Actually there will be more than hundred forms, each one has a set of icons, some of the overlaps.

Comment: How many total icons?  If it is more than, say, 50 and you dont have time for a designer to make them, go with the raters.  Provided they are small and are not going to be displaying gobs of them at a time, you should be fine.  I have had instances where list items had raster images on them to denote a shipping carrier (there were 5 distinct images) displayed maybe 1000 times without any problem...

Comment: Actually I have more than 500 images :)